# How do you return an xlsx file from an Azure function?

Tags: azure, file-io, azure-functions

I've seen some people try. I could not reproduce their results. Happy to use any language. I can create an xlsx from an HTTP Trigger. I want to return that file from another HTTP Trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have already generated the file, returning it is just creating an HTTP response with an attachment:

```cs
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(xlsxBytes);
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
    new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "Book1.xlsx" };
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
return result;
```