# Return an excel file from an HTTP triggered azure function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, python-requests, azure-functions, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create an Excel and return it using an Azure function in Python. the excel is successfully generated inside the function but I am not sure how to return that Excel from the Azure function. I found a similar answer in C#

[How do you return an xlsx file from an Azure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405338/how-do-you-return-an-xlsx-file-from-an-azure-function)

I am not able to convert it to Python using similar libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57506934/13308381), and use `xlrd` for xlsx file.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import xlrd

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    with xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx') as wb:
        with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"{[row for row in sheet]}")
```